# Unsure with Dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: python, recursion, dijkstra

With the help of so many people on this site, I have some brilliant code. Unfortunately, the Dijkstra Algorithm doesn't work. It is supposed to find the shortest distance between the AI and the player and move the AI closer to the player. I don't know how to get this to return a path and how to move the AI one step closer to the player or even if it works as I intended it to.

```
def search(x, y):
    if maze[x][y] == visblock():
        return False
    elif maze[x][y] == 3:
        return False
    elif maze[x][y] == player():
        print("Found Player")
        return True

    maze[x][y] = 3

    if ((x < 5 - 1 and search(x+1, y))
        or (y > 0 and search(x, y+1))
        or (x > 0 and search(x-1, y))
        or (y < 5-1 and search(x, y-1))):
            return True

    return False
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: Is the program not stopping? Maybe you have erroneously swapped +1 and -1 for the y: `y > 0 and search(x, y+1)` will make y go to infinity and `y < 5-1 and search(x, y-1)` will make y go to -infinity.

Comment: [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) also apply here.  You haven't researched how to return a path.  "I don't know how" is generally too broad -- it suggests a local tutor, rather than  SO.

Answer (score 1):

Dijkstra's algorithm for shortest A to B path works, even if your code does not.   [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) has code that you should be able to translate.

Since you can compute a fairly accurate minimum distance from each point to the goal, you would probably do better with the [A* improvement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) on Dijkstra.